# Cake 3: Mock Behavior for Model

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

In Cake 3 I am testing a behavior. Now I want to test if the behavior is used nicely when saving via a model. For that I need to mock some methods of the behavior.

I have searched for many ways how to mock them and add them to the model. In Cake 2.x we were able to register a custom behavior via the `ClassRegistry`. I have searched for how to do that in Cake 3 but could not find it.

Any body knows how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add mocks manually to the tables behavior registry using [**`ObjectRegistry::set()`**](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Core.ObjectRegistry.html#_set), which allows to add arbitrary objects.

```
$table = TableRegistry::get('FooBars');
$behaviorOptions = [];

$behaviorMock = $this->getMock(
    '\App\Model\Behavior\BazBehavior',
    ['some', 'mocked', 'methods'],
    [$table, $behaviorOptions]
);

$table->behaviors()->set('Baz', $behaviorMock);
```

Now your mocked behavior is registered on the table as `Baz`.

Comment: `$table->behaviors()->set(` is where I was looking for all time :) thanks!

Comment: I used the following code: `$table->behaviors()->set('Baz', $behaviorMock);`. Got this error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function set() on null`

Comment: @Bob Well, not much I can do from here, check why it's `null`, by default the table class [**constructor creates an instance of `\Cake\ORM\BehaviorRegistry`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/ab71c5f4e20d64282f106b7ae65471ecff8842e0/src/ORM/Table.php#L276) unless the `behaviors` option is passed to it.

Comment: It's tricky: when you leave the array where you place the mocked methods empty (`'some', 'mocked', 'methods'`) it will mock all methods automatically ;) Tricky and not clean?

Comment: @Bob If you don't want to mock any methods, then you'll have to pass `null`, not an empty array

Comment: oh great! Afterwards sounds logic :P